# Android accessing data on galaxy gear from note3 via bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, galaxy

I am working on android application for galaxy gear device.
I have two questions.

1. Can we access internet on galaxy gear via bluetooth?
2. If not then how to access data from galaxy note 3 via bluetooth.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, The Galaxy Gear apps can get internet data via the connected handset, however how to go about this is yet to be released by Samsung.